# Flutter issue with launching tel: and email

Tags: flutter

i am new to flutter, i made an app using webview and it works perfect but there's a href in my web with tel: , its not opening up the dialer in my phone but work fine in web browser.
i researched about url_launcher plugin but dont know where to put the code which opens the dialer when i click on tel:

my current code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new MaterialApp(
    routes: {
    "/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
    url: "https://www.test.com",
    ),
    },
  );
 }
}
```

your help is much appreciated !. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) for this. This will automatically open the dialer : `tel:+1 555 010 999`

```
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'tel:+1 555 010 999';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: but how to make it like it check the url and when tel comes in url , it will dial the number ..

Comment: can you add the code in the above code to make it work

Answer (score 1):

First add [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) in your pubspec.yaml and make your Uri like this,

```
final Uri _teleLaunchUri = Uri(
  scheme: 'tel',
  path: '+1 555 010 999', // your number
);
```

now make another function to launch your Uri,

```
_launchURL({Uri}) async {
  if (await canLaunch(Uri)) {
    await launch(Uri);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $Uri';
  }
}
```

at last call your "_teleLaunchUri" using "_launchURL" function.

```
onTap:(){
_launchURL(Uri: _teleLaunchUri.toString());
}
```

Comment: got it , but i have an anchor tag inmy web which have tel: ..no flutter button in app , just a web view which have the number asn anchor, will it work with that too?

Comment: and number is on anchor tag , not hardcoded

Comment: can you share your webview url?

Comment: use webview_flutter instead of url_launcher. in webview set your webview url and open it on real device. when you tap on number link it will open dialer on your mobile.

Comment: its not opening the dialer actually

Comment: trekandtales.com/test/test.php open this url on your mobile browser and tap on link and it will open dialer